# Set Column Label Alignment for one specific column header

Tags: wxpython

How to set alignment for specific col header in wxpython?

HEADER COL1 and COL2 has left alignment
HEADER COL3 has right alignment
HEADER COL4 has center alignment

```
HEADER |COL1  |COL2  |  COL3|  COL4   |
ROW1   |aa    |bb    |    56|    Y    |
ROW2   |cc    |hh    |    34|    N    |
```

For set aligment for cell I use:
self.grid.SetCellAlignment(row, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

But how do I set the alignment of a header of a particular column?

Very thanks!

Comment: https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.grid.Grid.html#wx.grid.Grid.SetColLabelAlignment

Comment: Thanks Rolf but SetColLabelAlignment is for all columns, no for particular column.